# Timeline chart for analogue and digital data in c#

Tags: .net, c#, graphs

I have both digital data e.g. open/closed & on/off and analogue values such as voltage, temperature etc and I would like to plot this on a timeline over 24 hours so the user can interept the data visually.

The values need to be kept in sync and shown stacked vertically so you can correlate the events ie what happens to the temperature when the door is opened.

Any ideas if any of the .Net/C# plotting or charting tools allow for this please.

Thanks
Mike