# Looking for a NuGet package for charts in Windows Forms Applications

Tags: c#, charts

**Yes, I do know there is a default charts functionality in Windows Forms.** But they are not quite what I am looking for. I'm looking for some customizable charts where I can adjust colour, size, position, etc programmatically, and hopefully asynchronously (i.e something similar to [HelloCharts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lecho.lib.hellocharts.samples&hl=en), but for C# Windows Forms. In fact, I would love if I could somehow port HelloCharts to C#.)

Also, would help if it were a NuGet package, but there doesn't seem to be much, except for [NuGet.Charts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Charts/), which doesn't seem to have documentation, so I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: I saw [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/timeline-chart-for-analogue-and-digital-data-in-c), but Nevron Charts isn't 100% free, it only has a trial, so it doesn't fit my needs.
**EDIT 2**: I also need zooming and panning features. ZedGraph fits all my needs except this one.
**EDIT 3**: See accepted answer.

Comment: CLR libraries have enough metadata for you to learn them using reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/), and it does have automatic zooming control by doing this:

> zedGraphControl.IsEnableWheelZoom = true;

It can make charts pretty quickly, and it has asynchronous operations for changing charts, and plus, some cool data analysis functions.

PS. It is also a NuGet package:

> PM> Install-Package ZedGraph